# How to avoid automatic cast for ArrayType in Spark (2.4) SQL - Scala 2.11

Tags: scala, apache-spark, casting, apache-spark-sql

Given the code in Spark 2.4 and scala 2.11

```
val df = spark.sql("""select array(45, "something", 45)""")
```

If I print the schema by using `df.printSchema()`, I see that spark makes an automatic cast to String `CAST(45 AS STRING)`.

```
root
 |-- array(CAST(45 AS STRING), something, CAST(45 AS STRING)): array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
```

I wonder if there is a way to avoid that automatic cast, but instead letting Spark SQL to fail with an exception? Assuming I call any action after that like `df.collect()`

This was just one query example, but it should apply to any query.

Answer (score 1):

This creates an ' ArrayType' column in the Dataframe.

From the [scaladocs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType) : `An ArrayType object comprises two fields, elementType: DataType and containsNull: Boolean. The field of elementType is used to specify the type of array elements. The field of containsNull is used to specify if the array has null values.`

Thus the ArrayType accepts only one type of columns in the Array.
If there are different types values passed to the `array` function, it will first try to cast the columns to the most accommodating type among the fields. If the columns are completely incompatible, then Spark will throw an exception. examples below

```
val df = spark.sql("""select array(45, 46L, 45.45)""")
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- array(CAST(45 AS DECIMAL(22,2)), CAST(46 AS DECIMAL(22,2)), CAST(45.45 AS DECIMAL(22,2))): array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: decimal(22,2) (containsNull = false)

df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [array(CAST(45 AS DECIMAL(22,2)), CAST(46 AS DECIMAL(22,2)), CAST(45.45 AS DECIMAL(22,2))): array<decimal(22,2)>]
```

Next one below, errors:

```
val df = spark.sql("""select array(45, 46L, True)""")
df.printSchema()

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'array(45, 46L, true)' due to data type mismatch: input to function array should all be the same type, but it's [int, bigint, boolean]; line 1 pos 7;
'Project [unresolvedalias(array(45, 46, true), None)]
+- OneRowRelation

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$3.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$3.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$6.apply(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$6.apply(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:303)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$8.apply(TreeNode.scala:354)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:352)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$3.apply(QueryPlan.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$3.apply(QueryPlan.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:77)
```

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that you are creating an array from columns that are in some dataframe. In that case, you can check in the schema of that dataframe that the input columns are of type `StringType`. In scala, it would look like this:

```scala
// some dataframe with a long and a string
val df = spark.range(3).select('id, 'id cast "string" as "id_str")

// a function that checks if the provided columns are strings
def check_df(df : DataFrame, cols : Seq[String]) {
    val non_string_column = df
        .schema
        .find(field => cols.contains(field.name) &&
                              field.dataType != DataTypes.StringType)
    if(non_string_column.isDefined)
        throw new Error(s"The column ${non_string_column.get.name} has type " +
                        s"${non_string_column.get.dataType} instead of StringType")
```

Then let's try,

```scala
scala> check_df(df, Seq("id", "id_str"))
java.lang.Error: The column id has type  LongType instead of string
  at check_def(<console>:36)
  ... 50 elided

scala> check_def(df, Seq("id_str"))
// no exception
```